compute the Euler class of tautological C-bundle over $CP^1$
This might be an old question. But since I have not found an explicit answer to this question, I put the question here.
The background is that we need to use a similar technique when we construct the Euler class for $S^1$-bundle. It is written in Bott, Tu, Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology, page 73.
To construct the $S^1$-bundle, we use the transition function $g_{\alpha\beta}: U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta} \rightarrow SO(2)$. By identifyin& SO(2) with the unit circle in the complex plane via $e^{i\theta}$, we consider the change of angle when we change the chart as $\theta_{\alpha} - \theta_{\beta} = \pi^*(1/i)log_{\alpha\beta}$. So the Euler class $e(E) = -(1/2{\pi}i)\sum_{\gamma} d(\rho_{\gamma}dlogg_{\gamma s})$ with $\rho_{\gamma}$ the partition of unity.
For the tautological C-bundle over $CP^1$, what is the explicit differential form of its Euler class? Is there any reliable result and detailed computing process that we can check?
